# In how ways can a football team be chosen given the stated constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A soccer team consists of 11 players. The team must be sorted into 3 attackers, 3 midfielders, 4 defenders, and 1 goalkeeper for today's match.Melissa is chosen to play goalkeeper. Linda wants to play attacker, and Robyn does not want to play defender. How many combinations are now possible?

For this I tried complementary method-> 46200 -1C1 * 1C1 * 8C2 * 6C3 * 3C3= 45640

However, the correct answer is 700. Could anyone explain that to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you said a bit more about how you came up with your formula

Comment: It looks like you subtracted the number of teams in which Linda is chosen to play attacker and Melissa is chosen as the goalkeeper from the total number of teams that could be formed.  However, you should subtract the number of teams in which Linda is chosen to play attacker, Melissa is chosen as the goalkeeper, and Robyn is chosen to play defender from the number of teams in which Linda is chosen to play attacker and Melissa is chosen as the goalkeeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give Melissa and Linda the positions they want and have nine positions for the remaining nine players.  It is easiest to choose the defenders first as you only have eight players willing to do that, so you can do it in ${8 \choose 4}=70$ ways.  You have five players left to choose the remaining two attackers from, which you can do in ${5 \choose 2}=10$ ways.  $70 \cdot 10=700$